# Redirecting to API/Docs/index.html folder in Lumen

Tags: laravel, routes, lumen, api-doc

So i have an API created with [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) with some documentation done with [Apidoc](http://apidocjs.com/) **outside of the public folder** and i'd like to serve it when the user goes to the URL `http://apidomain.com/docs`

This is the structure of the app

```
ProjectRoot
 ->API
   ->Auth
   ->Docs
   ->v1
 ->app
 ->bootstrap
 ->database
 ->public
...
```

Is there any way to create a route that sends the user to API/Docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done, it was actually my bad, when trying to call the file via routes it actually messed up the filepath for the other files. So when i looked in the dev tools on chrome i noticed i was getting 404's on my js and css files, hence the failure to load the ApiDoc